# Finding transconductance for common-source amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, biasing, transconductance

I wanted to check if the transconductance formula I am using is correct when I am dealing with an amplifier that has a small signal (Vsig) and a DC signal(Vs).

The schematic below is a little unclear but let's assume that it has a small signal and a DC signal as input to the gate.

[image]

I want to bias the amplifier so that when the amplifier is in the mid-band frequency range of small-signal input, there is an amplification of 11 V/V.

I know that we can find the gain at mid band by treating the coupling and bypass capacitors as short circuits which leads us to the gain equation:

Am = -(Rg/(Rg+Rsig))·gm·(RD||RL)

When I look for gm online I found many different forms and it kinda confuses me (are some forms of the equation more useful for certain applications?). I decided I would use this form:

gm = Kn·(VGS-Vt)

where kn = kn'·(w/L) and VGS is the DC component of the signal that is being fed into the gate. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

for JFETs and long_channel MOSFETS, the Id = K/2 * (W/L) * Ve^2,

where Ve = Veffective = (Vgs - Vt)

Now you want the transconductance (or gm, which is a vacuum tube parameter that means conductivity_mutual or G_mutual)

Given gm is d_I_out / d_V_in, we simply take the derivative (use that calculus)
and we get

dId/dVe = K/2 * W/L * [ 2 * Ve^1]

or gm = dIdrain/dVgate =  K * W/L * Ve

where you can see a 10X higher Ve produces 10X the transconductance.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is biased with a current source, so while a Vgs-based formula is correct, it will be more indirect (thus more chances to make an arithmetic error) and likely less insightful (since the relationship between g_m and the thing you control is more tenuous).

As a first pass, I would use a formula that's based on the drain current and fixed geometry/device parameters:

$$g_m = \sqrt{2(\mu_n C_{ox})\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)I_d}$$

Generally, the formula that reflects what you *directly* control is going to be more straightforward to work with and reason about.

As an aside/example, if I were on an integrated process and had control over W/L *and* the current, I'd use desired operating frequency to solve for system transconductance, and then size the FET to achieve the desired transconductance and \$f_t\$ with the minimum possible drain current, using a few such formulae that *directly* relate constraints I need to reach to things I control.

Edit - I didn't see that this question is long-inactive (it was recently bumped back to the homepage), but hopefully this answer may help a future reader.